# Submit mobile app form to ssl server

Tags: ssl, credit-card, mobile-application

I am using Phonegap to build an app which has a form with credit card info which data get submitted to my server. The server has SSL on top of it, From there using the payment gateway API I generate a token for this credit card in order to process the payment.

Is it safe to directly post to the server since i use a mobile app therefore a potential attacker could not interact with the form itself?

I could post the data directly to the payment gateway to retrieve that token but I would like the server solution since I can handle any errors/exception better.

What is your opinion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you post card data to your server then you, it, its network and hosting environment must all be PCI complaint which is a *major* undertaking and involves significantly more than simply using SSL: [Q: Am I PCI compliant if I have an SSL certificate?](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/#10)

> I could post the data directly to the payment gateway

Yes. Do this, its a no brainer.

Comment: i'll do that. After some digging it is the best option

Answer (score 0):

i really don't like Hybrid techs for mobile development. But, You need to create some validations like SSH pinning. Because an attacker can perform a mitm and maybe they can get some informations. Another problem is that using hybrid techs is more easy to perform a reverse engineering and maybe an attacker can get important data too.